# ML5: Error: You are passing a target array of shape 11342,1 while using a loss 'categorical_crossentropy'. 'categorical_crossentropy'expects targets

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am attempting to use the ML5 library for classification in a React app that I am building.

I am getting the following error in my browser

`Error: You are passing a target array of shape 11342,1 while using a loss 'categorical_crossentropy'. 'categorical_crossentropy'expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape [samples, classes].`

In several Github issues where this error is raised, the explanation is that `That error indicates you have just 1 type of objects in your dataset. You must have 2 or more different object classes in your dataset.` That is the explanation in the links [here](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/64) and [here](https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/issues/40).

I don't know what this means. I have 6 inputs and 2 outputs in my data. My input will look something like this

```
let inputs = {
  male: 1,
  female: 0,
  dob: 641710800000,
  // have more, but keeping it simple for this example...
}
```

and my output will look something like this

```
let output = {
  job: 1 // or 0, if they have a job or not, for example. i.e., two possible outputs
}
```

However, I'm still getting the error. Can someone help me understand why and how to fix it?

Here's my code below:

```
people_arr = json.voters_arr;
keys = ["male", "female", "dob"];

let model_options = {
  inputs: keys,
  outputs: ["job"],
  task: "classification"
};

let model = ml5.neuralNetwork(model_options);


for (let person of people_arr) {
  let inputs = {
    male: person.male,
    female: person.female,
    dob: person.dob
  };

  let output = {};
  output.job = person.job; // either 0 or 1
  model.addData(inputs, output);
}

model.normalizeData();

let train_options = { epochs: 100 }
model.train(train_options, whileTraining); // <-- error happening here
.then(() => {
  console.log("pre classify");
  return model.classify(new_person_arr);
})
.then((err, results) => {
  if (err) { console.log("error") }

  else {
    let new_arr = results.splice(100);
    console.log("results : ", new_arr);
    setValues({...values, results: new_arr })
  }
})
.catch((err) => { console.log("err : ", err) });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Categorical cross-entropy` expects a one-hot vector as a label, not a single number. For instance, let's say there are three people: `Michael`, `Jim`, and `Dwight`. `Michael` and `Jim` have jobs, `Dwight` doesn't. Let's say that not having a job puts you in category `0`, and having one puts you in category `1`. Labels in this case would look like this:

```
[[0,1],    # Michael's label
 [0,1],    # Jim's label
 [1,0]]    # Dwight's label
```

`Michael` and `Jim` are in category `1`, so they have a `1` at index `1` and a `0` at all other indices. `Dwight` is in category `0`, so he has a `1` at index `0` and a `0` at all other indices.

If you want to use a single number as a label (i.e. either a `0` or a `1`), you should use `sparse categorical cross-entropy` instead. `Sparse categorical cross-entropy` takes an integer as a label for each sample and assumes that there are categories from `0` to the highest value integer it sees. So it would work perfectly well with what you already have.

Comment: @Scott Is `new_person_arr` supposed to exist somewhere else in your code? Because the only place it's referenced is in that line.

Comment: Yes, it's an actual object or array. I `console.log` what I'm entering right before I call `.classify()`, and it's not `null` or `undefined`

Comment: @Scott I'm not sure then. Try posting another question and maybe someone else can help you out.